# Expectation of Geometric's squared conditioned by Bernoulli which is its first trial

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

In a production line, any product is defected with probability p independent
from all the other ones. Products are inspected until the first defective is encountered. Let
N be the number of inspections to obtain the first defective. Let Y be a Bernoulli random
variable indicating if the first item is defected or not. In other words Y = 1 if the first item
is defective and Y = 0 otherwise.

(a) What is the distribution of N ? What is E[N ] and $E[N^2 |Y = 1]$?

(b) What is $E[N^2 |Y = 0]$? (Leave your answer in terms of E[N ] and $E[N^2 ]$.

(c) Find $E[N^2 ]$ using parts (a) and (b).

(d) Using part (c) show that $Var(N )=\frac{1-p}{p^2}$

For part a) I know that N is Geometric and $E[N]=\frac{1}{p}$ but I don't know how to calculate $E[N^2 |Y = 1]$ doesn't it mean we find the first defective at the first trial?

For b) I think $E[N |Y = 0]$ is $E[N]+1$ since we know that first trial is not defective but again not sure about $E[N^2 |Y = 0]$

For part c) $ E[N^2]=E[N^2 |Y = 1]*P[Y=1]+E[N^2 |Y = 0]*P[Y=0]$

Part d) is simple.

Answer (score 3):

a) The random variable $N$ indeed has geometric distribution, and mean $\frac{1}{p}$.

We have, as you surmised,
$$E(N^2\mid Y=1)=1.$$
For given that we had a success on the first trial, $N$ has value $1$ with probability $1$.

b) As for $E(N^2\mid Y=0$, it is $E((1+N)^2)$, that is, $E(N^2)+2E(N)+1$. This is because we have "wasted" a throw.  Note that the conditional expectation is *not* $E(N^2)+1$.

c) Now, using the Law of Total Expectation, we obtain
$$E(N^2)=p+(1-p)(E(N^2)+2E(N)+1).$$
Solving for $E(N^2)$, we get
$$pE(N^2)=1+\frac{2(1-p)}{p}=\frac{2}{p}-1.$$

d) The variance of $N$ is $E(N^2)-(E(N))^2$. Substituting, we get that the variance is $\frac{2}{p^2}-\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p^2}$. This simplifies to $\frac{1-p}{p^2}$.

Comment: Hi, may you please explain more why we get $E(N^2|Y=0) = E((1+N)^2)$? Thanks.

Comment: It is because $N^2|\{Y=0\}$ and $(N+1)^2$ are identically distributed. If you condition on the event that the first item isn't defective, this experiment essentially restarts itself at the second inspection.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Do you have any way to prove they are identically distributed rigorously?

Comment: Sure. Notice that both $N^2|\{Y=0\}$ and $(N+1)^2$ are supported on the set $\{2^2,3^2,4^2,...\}$. Now compare $\mathbb{P}(N^2=n^2|Y=0)$ with $\mathbb{P}((N+1)^2=n^2)$ for any $n\geq 2$

Comment: Thanks, Matthew!