# Find expectation of geometric variable conditioned on Bernoulli variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Consider of sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli trials with the success parameter $p$. Let $X$ be the first time we get a success, and let $Y$ be the random variable determined if the first time is successful or not.

Then $X \sim Geo(p)$ and $Y \sim Bern(p)$. I need to find $E(X^2|Y=0)$.

I find another question that is relevant to my question,  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1666327/787230)

But I don't understand why we get $E(X^2|Y=0) = E((1+X)^2)$. Why we get this?

I'm very grateful to any help and answers.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?  If so, the answer is trivial and if not there is no answer.

Comment: No, X and Y are not independent? But if X and Y are independent. Why is it trivial?

Comment: @geetha290krm of course X and Y are not independent. If $Y=0$ then $X\neq 1$. Now, FactorY, you need to use the memoryless property of a Geometric distribution (or use reasoning similar to it).

Comment: @BenjaminWang OP did not state the question correctly. The relation between $X$ and $Y$ should have been stated here, not in the link.

Comment: @geetha290krm fair enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find another question that is relevant to my question,  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1666327/787230).

It is important to be clear about what $Y$ indicates in your link.

$$Y=\begin{cases}1 &:& X=1\\[1ex] 0 &:& X> 1\end{cases}$$
Recall too that geometric distributions are memoryless.

$$\mathsf P(X=s\mid X=1)=\mathsf P(X=s-1)$$

So $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X^2\mid Y=0) ~&=~ \mathsf E(X^2\mid X>1)\\[1ex] &=~\sum_{n>1} n^2\,\mathsf P(X=n\mid X>1)\\[1ex]&=~\sum_{n>1} n^2\,\mathsf P(X=n-1)\\[1ex]&=~\sum_{m\geq 1} (m+1)^2\,\mathsf P(X=m)\\[1ex]&=~\mathsf E((X+1)^2)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is very clear for me.

Comment: I don't undersand what is going on. No relation between $X$ and $Y$ is given in the question and you defined $Y$ in terms of $X$.

Comment: Indeed. The relation is defined in the link , @geetha290krm .

Comment: OP's calls that 'another question'. In this question there is no connection between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Kemp, I think Y must be 1 if X=1.

Comment: @FactorY  Yes, that was a typo.  Corrected.  Thank you.